# Magento 2: New order view inside account dashboard

Tags: magento2, dashboard

I need a second order view with some information about the order and additional upload functionality.

[image]

I tried to replicate how they did the "view order" page but although my links point to the right adress `/sales/order/upload/order_id/128`/ it leads to an error 404 page.

> vendor/module/frontend/sales_order_upload.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
    <update handle="sales_order_info_links"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.status" template="order/order_status.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.date" template="order/order_date.phtml"/>
            <container name="order.actions.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="actions-toolbar order-actions-toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" cacheable="false"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="sales.order.info.buttons">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons\Rss" as="buttons.rss" name="sales.order.info.buttons.rss" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Upload" name="sales.order.upload" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="order/items.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                            <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="order/tax.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" after="sales.order.upload"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> vendor/module/Controller/Order/Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;

class Upload extends \Vendor\Module\Controller\AbstractController\Upload implements \Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface
{
}
```

> vendor/module/Controller/AbstractController/Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

abstract class Upload extends Action\Action

{

protected $orderLoader;

protected $resultPageFactory;


public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Uploader page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
    if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
        return $result;
    }

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $navigationBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
    if ($navigationBlock) {
        $navigationBlock->setActive('sales/order/history');
    }
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

> vendor/module/Block/Order/Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Order;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

/**
 * Sales order upload block
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_template = 'order/upload.phtml';

protected $_coreRegistry = null;

protected $_customerSession;

protected $_paymentHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
}


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Order # %1', $this->getOrder()->getRealOrderId()));
        $infoBlock = $this->_paymentHelper->getInfoBlock($this->getOrder()->getPayment(), $this->getLayout());
        $this->setChild('payment_info', $infoBlock);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaymentInfoHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('payment_info');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * Return back url for logged in and guest users
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        if ($this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/*/history');
        }
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/form');
    }

    /**
     * Return back title for logged in and guest users
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getBackTitle()
    {
        if ($this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            return __('Back to My Orders');
        }
        return __('View Another Order');
    }

    /**
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInvoiceUrl($order)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/invoice', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShipmentUrl($order)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/shipment', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * @param object $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreditmemoUrl($order)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/creditmemo', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }
}
```

> vendor/module/view/frontend/order/upload.phtml

```
<div class="order-details-items ordered">
    <?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>

    <div class="order-title">
        <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items Ordered') ?></strong>
        <?php if ($_order->getTracksCollection()->count()) : ?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('tracking-info-link') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_items') ?>

    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
    <div class="block block-order-details-gift-message">
        <div class="block-title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Gift Message for This Order') ?></strong></div>
        <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessageForEntity($_order); ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <dt class="item-sender"><strong class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('From') ?></strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?></dt>
                <dt class="item-recipient"><strong class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('To') ?></strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?></dt>
                <dd class="item-message"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getEscapedGiftMessage($_order) ?></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBackUrl() ?>">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBackTitle() ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where did I go wrong, or how is magento 2 actually supposed to resolve such a url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

**=> vendor/module/Controller/AbstractController/Upload.php**

```
namespace vendor\module\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

abstract class Upload extends Action\Action

{

    protected $orderLoader;

    protected $resultPageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Uploader page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $navigationBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
        if ($navigationBlock) {
            $navigationBlock->setActive('sales/order/history');
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**=> vendor/module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="sales">
            <module name="vendor_module" before="Magento_Sales" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It worked, I'll have to research a bit more how routes.xml works.